# Can't delete Exchange server account from 10.9.5

Tags: server.app, exchange, macos

I did a clean install of 10.9 and then imported some old emails and my keychain.   Now my accounts keep showing an old exchange account for contacts from a previous employer.   I cannot delete this account.  Every time I delete it, it pops back.  HELP!

Comment: The account is on the server, go there and delete it there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your account isn't saved on your iPhone but rather on the server. You have to delete the account on the server, than it shouldn't pop up again.

Answer (score 0):

I did discover under /user/username/library/applicationsupport/addressbook there was a numbered folder with exchange files in it.   I deleted the entire thing closed and opened contacts and the problem was gone.

Re the previous answer,  I don't have an iPhone or access to the exchange server.